# C# ELSE doesnt return if wrong password

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, while-loop

Yesterday the code was working perfect.

The IS USERNAME EXIST using the bool readerRead still work and the success login with a valid username and password still work too.

But the bad password validation section doesnt work. If I enter a valid username but a wrong password, the code go to the ELSE of the first if(bool) and return the This username dosnt exist message. Supposed to return password doesnt match no..!?

```
private void button_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve the connection string from the settings file.
    string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.mattDatabaseConnectionString;

    // Open the same connection with the same connection string.
    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();

        // Read in all values in the table.
        using (SqlCeCommand query = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (username = @usern AND password = @passwd)", con))
        {
            //créé un paramètre pour passer la le string du textbox dans le SELECT -> WHERE
            //utiliser ces parametres prévient le SQL-Injection
            query.Parameters.Add("@usern", textBox_login_username.Text);
            query.Parameters.Add("@passwd", CalculateMD5Hash(textBox_login_password.Text));
            //créé un int pour regarder si le row exist

            SqlCeDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

            //prend les numéros des columns
            int columnUsername = reader.GetOrdinal("username");
            int columnPassword = reader.GetOrdinal("password");

            bool readerRead = reader.Read();

            //if username exist
            if (readerRead)
            {
                while (readerRead)
                {
                    string hash_pwd = CalculateMD5Hash(textBox_login_password.Text);
                    //if password match
                    if (hash_pwd == reader.GetString(columnPassword))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + reader.GetString(columnUsername) + ". YourID is: " + reader["id"]);
                    }
                    //if password doesnt match
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Your password doesnt match");
                        textBox_register_password.Clear();
                    }

                    //remet le bool readerRead à false sinon le while loop à linfini car true.
                    //ou mettre break;
                    readerRead = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This username dosnt exist");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For wrong password, as you are comparing both user name and password in the SQL query - no result is returned.

Change query to

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = @usern
```

Comment: work. yeah thats true.. I forgot I added the 'AND password = @passwd' this morning to be sure to select the proper row if there is 2 row with the same username. i'll use a different method then. thanks!!

Comment: Not only that but the wrong password logic can never run--if the password matches it matches on the second comparison also.

Comment: ok thanks.

I fixed the problem on the registring process making the column username Unique = yes and making a try catch.

Better like this. My other way was making any sens.. :D Thats the best way to learn !